# jQuery $.get() and $.ajax() doesn't get data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I have a script that is supposed to alert a message taken from a PHP file after a click event. I've tried both jQuery $.get() and $.ajax(), but both didn't worked.
$.ajax() works but alerts an empty message, $.get() alerts "null".

**load.php**

```
<?php
    $string = "prova";
    echo json_encode($string);
?>
```

**jquery_save.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#carica").click(function(){
        loadPHP();
    });
});

function loadPHP() {
    $.get( "load.php", function( data ) {
        alert(data)
    }, "json" );
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>This is just a test for Stackoverflow</title>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_save.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input style="background-image:url(img/lc-load.png);" type="submit" value="Carica" name="carica" id="carica">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this way I get the alert but with a "null" output.
I've tried this too:

**load.php**

```
<?php
    $string = "prova";
    echo $string;
?>
```

**jquery_save.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#carica").click(function(){
        loadPHP();
    });
});

function loadPHP() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'load.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data); 
        }
    });
};
```

This gives me an alert with noting inside. Both ways makes the page refresh after closing the alert message (and I don't want this happens).
I used another function with $.ajax() to give variables to another PHP file without problem, but I'm not able to take variables from PHP files.

Comment: If you call the php page directly, what shows up in the browser?

Comment: are you sure you're providing the correct php file path?

Comment: @epascarello it shows me "prova" with the quotes too.

Comment: @LorDex yes, all three files are in the same directory. I made a function that takes variables from html and passes them to PHP file that writes them all on a .txt file. It workes all fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prevent the default click action -

```
$("#carica").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    loadPHP();
});
```

Your alert does not occur because of the page redirection.

Comment: Thanks, it was that!
I've added "event.preventDefault();" before, but maybe I wrote it wrong because it doesn't changed nothing.

Now all worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a submit button which causes a submit event which isnt being handled.

try changing it like this

```
    <input style="background-image:url(img/lc-load.png);" 
type="button" value="Carica" name="carica" id="carica" />
```

Are you using a submit button to provide a fallback for browsers with javascript disabled? if that's the case you need to prevent the submit event